# ivyde copying local jars into .ivy2

Tags: ivyde

While everything seems to be working, I've noticed an odd behavior of the IvyDE eclipse plugin.

First, I've configured a resolve in ivysettings.xml to publish (and find) my projects artifacts in a custom directory (outside of .ivy2).

Eclipse and the IvyDE are resolving this just fine, but interestingly, my jar file is now being copied to and referenced from my .ivy2 cache.  Why is the plugin copying it from my custom directory into my .ivy2?

It seems to work fine, including Ivy->Resolve determining when there's an update, but it's just.. weird.  Why doesn't it just reference it directly from my custom directory when it obviously can find it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .ivy2 is the cache by default of every kind of resolver, even the file system ones. In order to avoid that useless copy of files from your local repository to your local cache, use the attribute `useOrigin` on the `caches` element in your ivysettings.xml.

For instance:

```
<ivysettings>
    <caches useOrigin='true' />
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem .... />
    </resolver>
</ivysetings>
```